# Count the number of duplicated values

Tags: r

I am trying to run function that will take one parameter, which is list of numbers, and count the duplicates.

Example:

```
number <- c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 4, 5)
```

In this case, the output will be 2, because only 1 and 2 have duplicates.

I know how to use for loop but not sure how to count duplicates.

```
count = 0
for (x in number){
    ...
}
```

Comment: or `sum(table(x) > 1)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tabulate the values, then count how many of those are greater than one.

```
x <- c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 4, 5)

sum(tabulate(x) > 1)
# [1] 2
```

Or, if you're looking for straight runs of duplicates, `rle` can be used as an alternative to tabulation.

```
with(rle(x), sum(lengths > 1))
# [1] 2
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution is written in **Python**.

```
import collections
number = [1,1,1,2,2,4,5]
x = collections.Counter(number)
len([i for i in x if x[i]>1])
```

It puts the numbers that appears more than once in a list and then counts how many elements are in that list.

Comment: The question is tagged R, not Python.